# installation of xunit.net in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xunit

i did not find **xunit.net Test extensions** in visual studio 2017 so what are the other possible ways to find it? or what if i install  **xUnit.net.TestGenerator**?

Comment: You should first make some effort on your own to solve the problem before asking community on SO for help. This what you ask for is easily available in xunit documentation which your should read first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html) is a complete guide, I only quote the main steps

1. Open your solution
2. Right click on the project and select `Manage NuGet Packages...`
3. Pick the tab `Browse`
4. Search for `xunit`.
5. Click `install`

Additionally, you might want to install `xunit.runner.visualstudio`. so the test runner will recognize the tests.

Answer (score 0):

while adding a new item search for

> x-unit

under the online tab, if you cant find it under the installed tab. Then install the template. After installation again search for xunit under the online tab or you can find the template at **online/templates/visual c#/visual studio essentials**. This time you were able to use the template.

Answer (score 0):

xUnit.net.TestGenerator is available to download in below link

[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YowkoTsai.xUnitnetTestGenerator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcch7.png)

After it install, restart visual studio then it is available like this in menu

[image]